# Select each record with first NULL Value after non-NULL value in record set

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, partition

I have a SQL query that returns a set of inspections on a piece of equipment with a column indicating the date a repair was made to the equipment represented by the record set.  If no repair was made at the time of inspection the field is NULL.  The piece of equipment in question will be repaired multiple times over its life.

I would like to find the subset of records within the query that have the minimum InspectionDate following each record with a non-NULL repair date with a NULL value in the RepairDate field.

For example:

```
InspectionDate            ReprairDate              OtherData
1/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
2/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
2/15/2010                 2/15/2010                ...
3/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
4/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
5/1/2010                  5/1/2010                 ...
6/1/2010                  6/1/2010                 ...
7/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
```

Should be paired down to:

```
InspectionDate            ReprairDate              OtherData
1/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
3/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
7/1/2010                  NULL                     ...
```

I know that this would be a fairly trivial matter using a cursor, but I am trying to get away from using them in general and feel like this could be done with some combination of PARTION, OVER and GROUP BY but I have not stumbled upon the right combination just yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(RepairDate) over (order by InspectionDate) as prevRepairDate
      from table t
     ) t
where prevRepairDate is not null and RepairDate is NULL;
```

In your data, the repair data is equal to the inspection date, when `RepairDate` is not `NULL`.  If this is not true, then the question is which date to use for determining the previous row.

Comment: Holy moly, that's a useful command. Looking forward to us moving off 2008 now :D

Comment: This is perfect!  I had never even seen the lag feature before.  As @franglais said, Holy moly that is a powerful tool!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.ReprairDate = NULL
FROM TABLE a
WHERE a.InspectionDate < '8/1/2010'
```